# Having trouble with Corona Table VIew

Tags: android, uitableview, lua, coronasdk, mobile-application

I was watching a video tutorial about Corona Table View, typed the same codes as in the tutorial but failed to display the data in the rows, but it displayed ni the tutorial. can someone check my code if I typed something wrong? [tableView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhQAu.png) here's the video tutorial:  [tutorial](http://masteringcoronasdk.com/biz-app-lesson/biz-apps-lesson-4-scrolling-data-with-tableview-widget/)

```
local widget = require ("widget")

local top = display.statusBarHeight
local listRecs = {}
local data = {"Altavas", "Balete", "Banga", "Batan", "Buruanga", "Ibajay", "Kalibo", "Lezo", "Libacao", "Madalag", "Makato", "Malay", "Malinao", "Nabas", "New Washington", "Numancia", "Tangalan" }
local list = nil

local function setup()
        list = widget.newTableView {
            top = top + 10,
            height = 960
    }

end

local function loadData()
    for x = 1, #data do
            listRecs[x] = {}
            listRecs[x].name = data[x]
    end
end

local function showRecords()

    local function onRowRender( event )
        local row = event.row
        local rowGroup = event.view
        local idx = row.index or 0
        local color = 0

        row.textObj = display.newRetinaText( listRecs[idx].name, 0, 0, "Century Gothic", 16 )
        row.textObj:setTextColor(color)
        row.textObj:setReferencePoint( display.CenterLeftReferencePoint )
        row.textObj.x = 0
        row.textObj.y = rowGroup.contentHeight * 0.35

        rowGroup:insert(row.textObj)


    end

    local function rowListener( event )

    end 

    for x = 1, #listRecs do
        list:insertRow {
            onRender = onRowRender,
            listener = rowListener
        }
    end

end


setup()

loadData()

showRecords()
```

Comment: I had this issue and found out my background color and text color defaulted to white.

Comment: Change the text or background color.

Comment: but the listview is defaulted to white, and I already set the text color to 0 which means black, right?

Answer (score 0):

Use:  https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newText.html 
instead of display.newRetinaText as well as use

```
    setFillColor, instead of row.textObj:setTextColor(color).
```

As well I encourage You to use new way of declaring display.newTExt that means
display.newText({text = "", fontSize = X, font = "", x = , y = }) instead of: display.newText(param1,param2,param3)